# OPCache dealing with multiple apaches

Tags: php, apache, opcache

In my application I use multiple Apache with load balances. I pretend start using OPCache with `opcache.validate_timestamps = off` for performance, but my doubt/concern is about cache reset. When I change a file is it necessary make a reset of OPCache in each Apaches?

Answer (score 1):

OPCache is cleared when when you restart the PHP module/daemon (e.g. restarting Apache for mod_php or restarting PHP-FPM, etc).

You can manually reset the opcache by calling `opcache_reset()` from a php script, however, this needs to be executed within Apache/PHP-FPM; you can not do it from a commandline. One method for doing that is to configure a restricted directory that is only accessible from the server itself or a trusted static IP (e.g. `<directory "dir">Require local</directory>`) and placing the php file there -- or using similar for a file restriction -- then using the browser from the server or curl via ssh/cmd (headless) to call the script to reset the cache without restarting.

Alternatively PHP provides the command `opcache_invalidate()`, but it is possible for this to result in issues (read more about potential issues with opcache). If your deployments are scripted, it is possible to invalidate the individual changed files.

validate_timestamps isn't necessarily "inherently" bad, but for production servers (where you rarely push updates and may already be restarting apache/php-fpm) it can be a bit overkill.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-invalidate.php

[Older blog post that describes some of the potential issues, can't guarantee it is still accurate.](https://tideways.com/profiler/blog/fine-tune-your-opcache-configuration-to-avoid-caching-suprises)